# Title attribute of wrapper element is being overridden by title attribute of SVG

Tags: svg

I have some HTML like so:

```
<a title="Close">
    <svg role="img" class="icon">
        <title>Close</title>
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/images/sprites.svg#close-small-icon">
            <svg id="close-small-icon" viewBox="0 0 9 9" width="100%" height="100%">
                <title>ic-close small</title>
                ...
            </svg>
        </use>
    </svg>
</a>
```

I want the tool-tip to show 'Close'. However, in Chrome, it is currently showing as 'ic-close small'. Why is this and is there any way to get this to work without removing the inner SVG title tag?

Comment: <use> cannot have an <svg> child element so your markup is invalid

Answer (score 2):

`<use>` does not have child elements.  Is your code snippet meant to indicate that the inner `<svg>` is referenced by the `<use>`?

You should be able to disable the `<title>` popup by add `pointer-events="none"` to the inner SVG. But I guess that's not a solution for you because it sounds like you aren't able to modify that SVG (?)

```html
<a title="Close">
    <svg role="img" class="icon">
        <title>Close</title>
        <svg id="close-small-icon" viewBox="0 0 9 9"
             width="100%" height="100%"
             pointer-events="none">
            <title>ic-close small</title>
            <circle cx="4.5" cy="4.5" r="4" fill="red"/>
        </svg>
    </svg>
</a>
```

Comment: I just copied the source form developer console. So <use> is a pointer to the SVG file?

Comment: Ah. It'll be the browser displaying the referenced SVG as a Shadow DOM.  Yes, the `<use>` element declares a refernce to another SVG element.  In this case it is the element with `id="close-small-icon"` in the file `/images/sprites.svg`.